# Controlling CSS using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to control CSS through AngularJS. I am using ng-class and ng-click for this purpose ..... I have made two function showError and showWarning for this purpose. I am try to change CSS through setting their properties true and false respectively

--------CSS---------

```
.error {
      background-color: red;
  }
.warning {
         background-color: orange;
  }
```

-------HTML---------

```
<div>
  <h2>  {{ message }} </h2>
   <ul>
       <li class="menu-disabled-{{ isDisabled }}" ng-click="stun()"> Stun</li>
   </ul>
    <div class='{ warning : {{ isWarning }}, error : {{ isError }} }'>
    {{ messageText }}</div>
    <button ng-click="showError()"> Simulate Error</button>
    <button ng-click="showWarning()">Simulate Warning</button>


</div>
```

-------JS-----------

```
  $scope.isError = false;
     $scope.isWaring = false;

     $scope.showError = function(){
         console.log("error here");
         $scope.messageText = "This is an error";
         $scope.isError = true;
         $scope.isWaring = false;
     }//showError

     $scope.showWarning = function() {
         console.log("warning here");
         $scope.messageText = "Just a Warning, Carry ON !!!";
         $scope.isError = false;
         $scope.isWaring = true;
     }//showWarning
```

I am successful to access the function and printing the messageText using ng-click but      can't change the CSS properties////

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular way is making that in template:

```
<div>
    <h2>  {{ message }} </h2>
    <ul>
        <li ng-class="{'menu-disabled': isDisabled}" ng-click="stun()"> Stun</li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-show="isError" class="error">{{ errorMessage }}</div>
    <div ng-show="isWarning" class="warning">{{ warningMessage }}</div>

    <button ng-click="isError=true;isWarning=false"> Simulate Error</button>
    <button ng-click="isWarning=true;isError=false">Simulate Warning</button>

</div>
```

No javascript code is needed and advisely, you shouldn't use javascript for that kind of **view** manipulations.

**EDIT:** You can use scope variables for message texts instead of static texts.

Comment: Sir the MessageText is a static content....I want to generate a dynamic content with the change of bg-color???.........plz help

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this

```
<div>
  <h2>  {{ message }} </h2>
   <ul>
       <li class="'menu-disabled' : isDisabled" ng-click="stun()"> Stun</li>
  </ul>     
<div class='error' ng-show="isDisabled" > {{ messageText }} </div>
<div class='warning' ng-show="isWarning" > {{ messageText }} </div>
<button ng-click="showError()"> Simulate Error</button>
<button ng-click="showWarning()">Simulate Warning</button>


   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, We have to pass boolean parameter in css also :

```
.warning-true{
         background-color: orange;
  }
.error-true{
    background-color: red;
}

 <div class=" warning-{{ isWarning }} , error-{{ isError }} ">{{ messageText }}  </div>
    <button ng-click="showError()"> Simulate Error</button>
    <button ng-click="showWarning()">Simulate Warning</button>
```

and js reamin same.